# how do I update hibernate_sequence in Grails using oracle 11g database?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, squirrel-sql

I imported some data into my schema and I have one sequence for all my tables. In my old app, the sequence was around 1000, but this new sequence is starting at 4, and thus I am getting conflicts when trying to enter a new row. Is there a way to update the sequence or is there a way to set the sequence to a certain number during db creation? I don't mind doing a create-drop and importing the data again. I basically just want to set the sequence to start at 1000. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to increase the increment, access the sequence and then reset the increment, e.g.:

```
alter sequence [sequence name]
increment by [desired value minus current value];

select [sequence name].nextval from dual;

alter sequence [sequence name]
increment by 1;
```

I got this syntax from: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I wish I could accept both answers, and give both of you points but this one helped me more because my sequence was already there and I just needed to update it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set up the start number of the sequence when creating it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence
    MINVALUE 1000
    START WITH 1000
    INCREMENT BY 1;
```